# Bootstrap dropdown in collapse not showing on first attempt

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu inside a nav-collapse.

When I reduce the window's width (eg: 700px), the navbar correctly collapses, then I click on btn-navbar to un-collapse it, then I click on the dropdown, but it does not drop down, the menu does not show. If then I collapse and un-collapse again, the dropdown starts working.

The same happens when the window's width is small from the beginning.

It's like the height of the collapsed part was fixed at the beginning, and it doesn't let the dropdown do its thing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" />
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">

                    <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
                    <button class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

                    <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
                    <div class="nav-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Anonymous <b class="caret"></b>
                                </a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href=''><i class='icon-chevron-right'></i> Login</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href=''><i class='icon-plus'></i> Register</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Bootstrap v2.2.0

Firefox 16.0.2

Comment: When the window is <700 to hide the navbar, then clicking the expand navbar button, the menu "Anonymous" is open and can't be closed.

Comment: @popnoodles So what should I do? The code I'm using is from the documentation, I think I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: i can't reproduce what you're getting.

Comment: @popnoodles I guess bootstrap is not really crossbrowser and responsive after all.

Comment: @popnoodles The behavior you're describing is 2.1, not 2.2. I almost made the same mistake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A lot of people were reporting this as a bug on the repo (eg. [Issue #5671](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5671), [Issue #5890](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5890), [Issue #6019](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6019)).

In response to #5671, someone points out that [as per the docs on responsive Navbar](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar), when using the class `navbar-collapse` you must also include `collapse`.  Seems that your example suffers from this same (albeit easily overlooked) flaw.

Here's a working example of your code, the only difference being adding the `collapse` class:

### [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/I6ucRV)

Comment: They must have changed the docs as I didn't type, I copy-pasted and modified.

Comment: Hmm - trying this Plunker example I see that when the hamburger appears I can no longer view the drop down. Is the bug back? I have a similar problem and do not see the drop down at all when the hamburger appears :(

Comment: @user1895637 Works for me. What browser are you using? Are there any errors logged in the console?