# bootstrap menu toggle first click not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Im using bootstrap-collapse.js v2.3.0, but for some reason on the first click the menu just appears and doesnt slide down.
I also noticed the height doesnt say `auto` , it says `205px`. I dont have the menu set to this height anywhere in the CSS.
After the first click, when I go to toggle it closed, everything seems perfect, the height toggles between 0 and auto and there is a smooth transition as opposed to it instantly appearing.

Im unsure as to what code to include as it seems to be the bootstrap toggle that is the problem, 
however here is the html...
I removed irrelivent bits of code..

```
<div class="navbar">
 <div class="navbar-inner">

              <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="brand visible-phone">
    Categories
  </a>
        <a data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="nav-collapse">
     <ul class="nav">
        <li> //more code </li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">//more code<<b class="caret"></b></a>



         <ul class="dropdown-menu" >

            <li>//code</li>
              <ul>

                        <li>//code</li>

              </ul>

         </ul>

    </li>

    <li>//code</li>
```

but here is a link to the site...

http://bc_mobile.hailstormcommerce.com/

Comment: I would suggest switch to 2.3.0 latest .. most issues will be resolved

Comment: Thanks, I just did so but unfortunately no improvement

Comment: Please put all your javascript files in footer .. it will help page load faster . secondly the tabs.js file ..bootstrap already have tabs.js included in the main js

Comment: I had the same problem. The solution is the accepted answer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572205/bootstrap-dropdown-in-collapse-not-showing-on-first-attempt)

Answer (score 0):

Plz check this jsfiddle [JSfiddle for you with navigation](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/VvgS2/show/)

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
   <i class="icon-bar"></i>
  </a>

    <a class="brand" href="">New Icon Menu</a>

    <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
            <li><a href=""><i class="icon-home icon-2x"></i> Home<br></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-pencil icon-2x"></i>About Us</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-briefcase icon-2x"></i>Portfolio</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href=""><i class=" icon-envelope icon-2x"></i>Contact Us</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks,  but im not sure what you are showing me with that link